# What is the domain of definition that is understood for $f(z)=\operatorname{Arg}\left(\frac1z\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the domain of definition that is understood for $f(z)=\operatorname{Arg}\left(\frac1z\right)$?

I am surprisingly bad at complex analysis, but a dumb question unanswered is worse than a dumb question answered :).

---

So I feel I fundamentally don't understand this problem yet, but here is what I have done:

$\frac1z=\frac1{x+iy}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$

And hence we want(?) $\arctan\left(-\frac{\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}{\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}}\right)=\arctan(-\frac{y}{x})$ hence we are defined for all but $x\ne 0$

---

So I suppose all but $\text{Re}(z)=0$

Comment: This doesn't look right.  $f$ is defined at $z=i$, is it not?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I am definitely wrong, hmmm. I didn't notice that since this is not natural to me yet(never did complex numbers in highschool or in any previous courses)

Comment: I guess your confusion arises from the $\arctan$ which is *related* to the argument but not the *same* as the argument. This is why many computer programming languages have an [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function.

Comment: the domain is all nonzero complex numbers. the $arg(1/z) = -arg(z) \mod (2\pi)$

Comment: @Abel Edit : Oh whoops, I get it

Comment: my job is done.

Comment: you are welcome. complex analysis by ahlfors is a great textbook to learn complex numbers from. he takes is from scratch without any compromises. take a look at it.

Comment: @Abel I'll give it a look, I am working through Complex variables by James Brown & Ruel Churchill and it is great so far, but some answers aren't there and some things feel a little lacking.

Comment: applied math folks seem to like churchill and brown. i  think it trains you to do a lot computations. that is good.

Comment: @abel It does indeed, and the computations don't seem unmotivated for once, so I actually *enjoy* doing the exercises.(Not to say I don't love doing questions in abstract algebra, but in that case they aren't merely computations)